# Deploy Next Website with Vercel ...Error: "npm run build" exited with 1 "

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, vercel, aruba

Sto cercando di risolvere questo problema da 1 settimana e anche cercando tra le varie risposte ma non funziona.

Ho un webSite sviluppato con React e Next.js. Ho comprato il dominio su Aruba ma devo fare il deploy tramite Vercel per poi cambuare il dominio.

Ora il problema è che quando faccio il deploy su Vercel mi si blocca con questo errore:
" Build Failed
Command "npm run build" exited with 1 "

Ho provate a settare nella sezione Build & Development in npm run dev o npm run build o npm build.

Qualcuno che riesce ad aiutarmi, perfavore?